# How to make the zenity --notification button execute a command

Tags: linux, notifications, zenity

I'm trying to make the "Do default action" actually do something, and I've been experimenting with `zenity --notification --listen`, but no matter in what order or way I put the command in, it just says: `Could not parse command from stdin`

I'd love any sort of help.

Comment: `echo 'message: Hello!' | zenity --notification --listen`

Comment: @nsilent22 Thanks, that worked! But I'd love to know where you found this out and what other commands I can execute using Zenity.

Comment: `man zenity`: Listen for commands on stdin. Commands include 'message', 'tooltip', 'icon', and 'visible' separated by a colon. For example, 'message: Hello world',  'visible:  false',  or 'icon:  /path/to/icon'.  The  icon  command  also accepts the four stock icon: 'error', 'info', 'question', and 'warning'

Comment: Thank you so much, I honestly didn't think I'd be this blind when going through man pages, but do you know if I can make the button on the default notif do something?

Comment: Sorry, there is no such button in my system. Fist comment to this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192377/239754 says it's not zenity's, but distro (or notification system) feature.